# Create a bootable USB from iso file in Linux

Tags: usb, live-usb, iso, dd

Do you want to write your favorite Linux-iso to a USB-stick?

Are you confused by all the forum posts on the internet?

Below is the quick and mostly fail safe way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

First use gparted to find if your usb stick is named sdb/sdc or something else. In a terminal

`cd` to the folder where the *.iso is located. In my case

```
cd Downloads
```

write the iso to the usb stick and make sure it was written with sync

```
sudo dd if=file.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=1MB && sync
```

where `sdX` refers to your USB drive.

In my case

```
sudo dd if=debian386.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1MB && sync
```

It is done or it should be done, but in the Linux/GNU world it might not be.
Check if it is done by rebooting or booting the computer where you want to run the installation or live-usb

if you do not know what dd or sync is then

```
man dd && man sync
```

Be careful with dd because it is powerful and will wipe your drive without asking for permission. It thinks you are God and like a slave executes your commands. It means you have to know your tools or they will bite you hard.

**IMPORTANT**: make sure you refer to the correct drive in your command otherwise it is possible that you lose your data.